# SAS data Hebrew encrypted

Tags: sas

I am working on Israel data where some fields are in Hebrew (encoded as well I suppose).

[image: data view for Gender as is in data]

When I try to import the data, I get special characters. I want to get English form of it (M,F) directly from the data as I have no clue what these encodings mean.

Alternate in MS Access

In Access, I tried importing the data:

[Access import]

I get fields as:

[enter image description here]

Then I use these values in Google Translate to get the result:

[enter image description here]

If there is anything that someone could suggest for SAS.

Can't put more images as it says you need at least 10 reputation to post images.

Comment: It looks like you are missing some link information here. You can paste relevant text into your post to make your question more understandable.

Comment: How are you importing the data?  Perhaps you need to embed the right encoding option (or set the system option).  Please show us what you have tried..